# How substitute an AbsolutePoint for a car drawing or car icon?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, graphs-and-networks, drawing

$CAR$

```
Graphics[{Scale[{RGBColor[0.25, 0.63, 0.85], 
         Polygon[{{-4, 0}, {-3.85, 0.7}, {-3.2, 0.7}, {-3, 1.15}, 
             {-1.3, 1.15}, {-0.8, 0.7}, {0, 0.45}, {0, 0}, {-4, 0}}], 
         RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1], Polygon[{{-3.1, 0.7}, {-2.95, 1.1}, 
             {-2.1, 1.1}, {-2.1, 0.7}}], 
    Polygon[{{-1.9, 0.7}, {-1.9, 1.1}, 
             {-1.35, 1.1}, {-0.9, 0.7}}], GrayLevel[0], 
         Disk[{-1.5, 0.91}, 0.15], GrayLevel[0], Disk[{-3, 0}, 0.4], 
         Disk[{-1, 0}, 0.35], GrayLevel[0.4], Disk[{-3, 0}, 0.15], 
         Disk[{-1, 0}, 0.15]}, {Sqrt[1 - 150000^2/300000^2], 1}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 0}, {-0.4, 1.2}}, ImageSize -> {90, 70}]
```

$PROJECT$

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[r*(y/x), {x, 20, 42}, {y, 20, 42}, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[RGBColor[1., 0.77, 0.], Opacity[1.], 
    AbsoluteThickness[1.999], Dashed], 
     ContourLabels -> False, 
  Contours -> {27, 28, 28.5, 29.5, 47, 49, 50, 52, 94, 96, 97, 99}, 
     ContourShading -> {Red, Orange, Red, Orange, Red, Orange, Red, 
    Orange, Red, Orange, Red, Orange, Red}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\"Was\",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\
\)\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\" \",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, \
     0]]\)\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\"I\",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\
\)\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\" \",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, \
     0]]\)\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\"Speedy\",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\
\)\!\(\*\nStyleBox[\"?\",\nFontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\)  if your \
speedometer reads ", 
           NumberForm[r, {4, 0}], 
     "mph, you're actually traveling to: ", 
     NumberForm[r*(y/x), {4, 0}], mph}], Axes -> True, Ticks -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 674, 
     AxesOrigin -> {20, 20}, AspectRatio -> 0.65, 
  Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{x, 42}, {x, y}}], 
     Line[{{20, y}, {x, y}}]}, {AbsolutePointSize[32], 
     Point[{x, y}]}}], 
   {{x, 30, "old tire diameter inches"}, 20, 42, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{y, 30, "new tire diameter inches"}, 20, 
  42, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{r, 45, "Speedometer reading in mph"}, 30, 80, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: your code is malformed. Try pasting again. Convert the cell to InputForm first, then copy/paste the result. Make sure to make a copy of the cell first.

Comment: Thank you, I did it, I hope that now it works ;)

Comment: I would like to increase the PlotLabel font size. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
car = Graphics[{Scale[{RGBColor[0.25, 0.63, 0.85], 
         Polygon[...

Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{x, 42}, {x, y}}], 
   Line[{{20, y}, {x, y}}]}, {AbsolutePointSize[32], 
   Inset[car, {x, y}]}}
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would like to increase the PlotLabel font. Do you know or somebody knows how to do it?